# setuid program owned by non-root user

Tags: setuid

I have a setuid program (getpwd) that runs as expected only when owned by root.

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 7981 2011-11-17 18:28 getpwd*
```

In other words when my program is executed on the command line by user "alice" all works fine

The program opens a file in directory `/home/secure` and print the contents to screen.

```
alice@devbox:/home/alice/tmp$ ./getpwd
setuid is working
```

However when I change the ownership and set setuid of the file:

```
chown secure:users getpwd
chmod 4755 getpwd

-rwsr-xr-x 1 secure users 7981 2011-11-17 18:28 getpwd*
```

The program does not run when executed as user "alice".

```
alice@devbox:/home/alice/tmp$ ./getpwd
cannot open file /home/secure/test ...
```

Why is this happening?

```
ls -ld /home/ /home/secure/
drwx--x--x 2 secure users 280 Nov 18 11:16 /home/secure/

ls -ld /home/secure/*
-rw------- 1 secure users 33 Nov 15 14:35 /home/secure/test
```

Comment: What's the output of `ls -ld /home /home/secure /home/secure/pathname` ?

Comment: When run as root : `code` ls -ld /home/ /home/secure/*
drwxr-xr-x 16 root   root   392 Nov 15 14:32 /home/
-rwsr-xr-x  1 secure users   37 Nov 15 22:15 /home/secure/list.sh
-rwsr-xr-x  1 secure users 7965 Nov 15 22:16 /home/secure/runscript
-rw-r--r--  1 secure users  165 Nov 15 22:16 /home/secure/runscript.c
-rw-------  1 secure users   33 Nov 15 14:35 /home/secure/test`code`

Comment: Can you [edit] that into your existing question? The comments make monospaced pastes illegible. :( -- and don't forget the `ls -ld /home/secure` -- I want to know owner and permissions on that directory, too.

Comment: the file test is set as -rw-------. This is correct. No one should be able to read the file except user secure.

Comment: What is the code of the _program_? Is it compiled executabe or a *script?* SUID does not work for scripts.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I ensure that only user "alice" can run the setuid program owned by secure?

There are two possible approaches. One uses nothing but traditional Unix permissions and the other uses newfangled ACLs.

#### Traditional Unix

Create a new group; perhaps `ALICE` or something obviously different from an `alice` user account. Make sure `alice` is a member of `ALICE` in `group(5)`. (`vigr(8)` is a great way to edit the `group(5)` file.) Set the ownership of your `getpwd` program `secure:ALICE` and *remove* world execute privileges on the file. Then, only `secure` and members of the `ALICE` group can execute the setuid `getpwd` program.

If `alice` is just a stand-in for a potentially larger group of people, then maybe name the group `SECURE`. (Upper case is just convenient for my description. You don't have to stick with upper case.)

#### Newfangled ACLs

```
setfacl -m u:alice:x getpwd
```

The `setfacl(1)` program is a bit complicated, but it allows you to create far more complex permissions than the traditional Unix permissions. Because these are pretty different, most systems I have seen don't have them turned on by default -- that requires the `acl` option to `mount(8)` when mounting the filesystem. You would need to add `acl` to the filesystems in `/etc/fstab` that need the extra permissions. (You don't need to reboot to make it available, though; `mount /file/system -oremount,acl` would be sufficient for as long as the filesystem is mounted -- typically until reboot.)

I suggest sticking with the traditional Unix method.

Comment: Thanks. Should I set the getpwd to g+s ?

Comment: That option completely slipped my mind. Yes, that should work.