# Race Condition Vulnerability Lab

Tags: c, linux, security, command-line, race-condition

I have a lab where I have to use this SeedUbuntu virtual machine for a race condition vulnerability. There is C program that I need to utilize to create the attack so I can access the shadow file. Here is the link to the lab with the programs and PDF information: http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs/Vulnerability/Race_Condition/
What I am confused about is exactly how to approach this. I can compile and run the vulp.c program and the shell script in seperate terminals but what do I do next? What sort of code or commands do I need to execute? I'm so confused and I would really appreciate any assistance in solving this task! Thank you!

```
/*  vulp.c  */

#include <stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#define DELAY 10000

int main()
{
   char * fn = "/tmp/XYZ";
   char buffer[60];
   FILE *fp;
   long int  i;

   /* get user input */
   scanf("%50s", buffer );

   if(!access(fn, W_OK)){
       /* simulating delay */
        for (i=0; i < DELAY; i++){
           int a = i^2; 
        }

        fp = fopen(fn, "a+");
        fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, fp);
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), strlen(buffer), fp);
        fclose(fp);
   }
   else printf("No permission \n");
}
```

Comment: Do I need to modify this vulp program?

Comment: I need to make a symbolic link in this program? I'm new to C and Linux so this is very alien for me!

Comment: Or am I creating a link in the terminal once I run vulp.c?

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved when I was a student at SU,

two different shells are executing two loops simultaneously. keep_run will continuously run

the vulp.c program with input string passed in a file called FILE.

keep_attack will creat the file first and then remove it and then it create a symbolic link to our targeted file that belongs to the root. We need the following order of execution of commands in order for our attack to succeed:

1. keep_attack >> touch /tmp/XYZ
2. keep_run >> running vulp and checking the file (doing the access command)
3. keep_ attack >> rm /tmp/XYZ
4. keep_attack >> ln –s target_file /tmp/XYZ
5. keep_run >> reaching the command that tries to OPEN the file

*(Make sure the program has the set-uid and is owned by the root -- [setuid program owned by non-root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179462/setuid-program-owned-by-non-root-user))

Answer (score 0):

First, you must compile the vulp.c program

```
gcc vulp.c -o vulp
```

Next you must change the `vulp` executable to a set-UID program:

```
sudo chown root vulp
sudo chmod 4755 vulp
```

Now, notice in the source code of `vulp.c` that when `vulp` is ran we first must get input from the user. The program stays at the scanf command until input is provided. So, there is no access control check until the user provides input. That is, we never get to `if(!access(...))` until after input is provided.

Now before we run `vulp` let us first change `/tmp/XYZ` to point to `/dev/null` because we know our regular user account has write access on this file. If we can pass the `if(!access(...))` access control test, we can get into the critical section. So the idea is that `/tmp/XYZ` points to `/dev/null` during the access control check and we pass the check and get into the critical section. Then you simulate having a slow machine with the DELAY loop. While this loop is executing we want to change our symbolic link of `/tmp/XYZ` to point to `/etc/shadow`.  Thus, when the open() command is executed on `/tmp/XYZ`, we are opening `/etc/shadow` for write.

To summarize:
Step 1 in terminal 1:

```
ln -sf /dev/null /tmp/XYZ
```

Step 2 in terminal 2:

```
./vulp
```

Step 3 in terminal 2:
Supply the input that you want written to `/etc/shadow` file

Step 4 in terminal 1 (do this quickly after supplying input):

```
ln -sf /etc/shadow /tmp/XYZ
```

After these steps, whatever you supplied as input in Step 3 will be written to `/etc/shadow`